# Google Analytics Regex error trying to specify number of matching digits in URL

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am writing a Google Analytics query in JavaScript to get page views for pages of a certain URL structure.  The below works:

```
'filters': 'ga:pagePath=~some/path/here/\\d{4}$'
```

But I get an "invalid value for filter parameters" error when I specify that 1-4 digits at the end should match, like so:

```
 'filters': 'ga:pagePath=~some/path/here/\\d{1,4}$'
```

I'm not sure what I need to change to match URLs that end with 1-4 digits.  Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't it actually be `\d` instead of `\\d` since it is a javascript regex?

Comment: `\d{1,4}` is correct regex for matching 1 to 4 digits, see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kT6jZ6) ..in theory ga should accept that as well.

Comment: I started with that, but \d{4} returns no results, whereas \\d{4} returns what looks like the appropriate URLs (but none with 1-3 digits).

Comment: \d{1,4} is correct regex, which is why I'm confused by getting an error when I use it.